# Photon Server 3 - Did not reach license monitor #0 error

Tags: cross-platform, multiplayer, socketserver

I've downloaded the free license - (Photon 3 - Free License (100 CCU, no expiry)) and replaced the current trial license (30 days limited) with it, then I try to start my photon server, but it doesn't work. I check the log file and find this, 'Did not reach license monitor #0'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two solutions for this problem, with #1 being the most convenient:
1) Start with no license file (delete it from the directory): Photon will 
run in 20CCU mode 
2) Use the 30 day trial from the website again